# "What" or "who"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-choice, pronouns

Imagine having to speak about a profession that no longer exits or is no longer called what it used to be (e.g. "beadsman," "friar," "apothecary"). The audience knows that the talk is about a dead profession, but they don't know yet what it is exactly and whether it was performed by a man or woman. Now, you want to ask them a question to ease them into the subject. The question asks if any of the audience knows about the profession.

Do you ask:

> a. Does anyone know **what** an "apothecary" is?
>
> b. Does anyone know **who** an "apothecary" is?

"What" suggests that "apothecary" could be something not someone, which may throw the audience out of balance (remember that they have very little background; they can get easily confused)

And

"Who" sounds as if I were asking about his identity or something

Please help.

Comment: *Who* asks for the identity of a specific person; I think most people would treat any profession, whether contemporary or obsolete, as a *what*: "What's a stockbroker? What's a programmer?", but "Who's your stockbroker? Who was the lead programmer on this app?"

Comment: As @StoneyB says, a profession or occupation is inanimate, whereas the person doing it is animate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A profession is a thing, not a person.

```
 Q. What is a carpenter? 
 A. A person who works with wood.

 Q. Who is the carpenter?
 A. Dave.
```

By the way, a friar is neither a profession nor obsolete. A friar is a member of a mendicant religious order (Franciscans, for example) and they still exist today. A friar could practice many different professions.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. And many thanks for the additional comment.

Answer (score 2):

If I wanted to ease into a conversation where we'd discuss an obscure profession, I might ask:

> *Does anyone know what an apothecary **does**?*

This is a rather common way of wording such a question, as was done in a series of articles published by *The Guardian*:

- [What does a research analyst do](http://www.theguardian.com/careers/so-what-does-a-research-analyst-do-exactly), exactly?
- [What does a civil engineer do](http://www.theguardian.com/careers/what-does-civil-engineer-do)), exactly?
- [What does a music manager do](http://www.theguardian.com/careers/what-does-a-music-manager-do), exactly?

If you are absolutely sure the career is obsolete, I suppose you could change the question to the past tense, if you liked that better:

> *Does anyone know what a haruspex **did**?*

Comment: Thank you, BUT is this wrong: "Does anyone know what an apothecary?"

Comment: @asef - Yes, that's wrong. It needs a verb; e.g.: "Does anyone know what an apothecary *is*?" or, "Does anyone know what an apothecary *does*?" If you wanted to end with the word _apothecary_, you could ask: "Does anyone know anything *about* apothecaries?"

Comment: Thank you. The missing verb was an oversight. Apologies.