# Is it wrong to begin this sentence with "on hindsight"?

Tags: sentence-usage, adverbial-phrases

Is it wrong to begin this sentence with **on hindsight**:

> On hindsight, I sense I would not be what I am today if I had the same maturity and wisdom what I have now, twenty five years ago?

Comment: "**In** hindsight, I believe I would not be **who** I am today if twenty five years ago I **had had** the same maturity and wisdom **that** I have now" is a bit more grammatically correct.

Comment: @JamesWirth Don't we need to hyphenate the "twenty five"? Oh, and "who" vs "what" is not entirely undisputed ([example](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/89077/when-to-use-who-vs-what)).

Comment: @MrLister technically you're **supposed** to hyphenate the twenty-five, but you can usually get away without it - I usually forget to ;-). Secondly, you're right about "who" and "what", I guess both of them could be used in this context. Its just that I though "who" suited the sentence a bit better (because he's describing his personality)

Answer (score 3):

It's fine to begin a sentence with an [adverbial phrase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adverbial_phrase).

Note that the most common preposition used with [hindsight](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/hindsight) is **in**, not **on**. Here is an [NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in%20hindsight%2Con%20hindsight&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cin%20hindsight%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Con%20hindsight%3B%2Cc0) showing the difference in usage.  Here is an example that shows the use of the adverbial phrase at the beginning of the sentence, with the preposition **in**.

> In hindsight, it would have been better to wait

As for the rest of the sentence:

[sense](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/sense): an ability to understand, recognize, value, or react to something, **especially any of the five physical abilities** to see, hear, smell, taste, and feel

[think](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/think): to believe something or **have an opinion** or idea

[same](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/same?q=same%20as) is normally used together with **as** rather than **what**.

> **In** hindsight, I **think** that I would not be what I am today if I had the same maturity and wisdom **as** I have now, twenty five years ago.